# execute a stored procedure that returns a " completed succesfully " clue

Tags: sql-server-2005, c#-4.0, return-value, asp.net-4.0

i have a stored procedure

```
UPDATE tblTime
SET TimeOut = DATEADD(HOUR,8,TimeIn)
WHERE tId =
( 
   SELECT MAX(tId)
   FROM tblTime
   WHERE UserId = 3571
)
```

although there's no question really, in that case if it did succeed in this query

cause even if the field is empty or if it has value,
it will in this case succeed

but i do need it for future other queries... and also ,
 in this case i want the C# code to report 
not only that it was requesting query to be execute - meaning it did happen,

but to get an **actual answer** from sql server
 as a return value that c# could use or turn into `Boolean`

Comment: Your question is confusing. Stored procedures always return zero if they succeed, and a non-zero value if they fail. Additionally, if a sproc fails due to an error, the C# code will throw that as an exception which you can catch and handle appropriately.

Comment: In this case you may want to return `@@RowCount` in an output parameter to indicate whether or not a row was updated.  Not finding a suitable row is not a SQL error, but it may be an application error that you wish to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have managed to do somthing about this so i can specify a condition inside sql server stored proc

declare an `OUTPUT` variable(PARAMETER) then

set its value to say 1 if condition is met and -1 if not

then 
in c# set a function as follows 
in this example outpout parameter is named `ERROR`

```
   public static int UpdateTblViaStoredPRoc(string SPname, int UserID)
        {
            int message = 0;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Initial Catalog=****DBNAME HERE***;Integrated Security=True"))
            {

                con.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SPname, con);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uid", UserID);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ERROR", SqlDbType.Int);

                cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                 message =(int) cmd.Parameters["@ERROR"].Value;

                con.Close();
            }
            return message;
        }
```

stored proc is then allways following the same pattern

declare `ERROR`  parameter, set a condition to output the ERROR accordingly :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[nameofProc]
@UId Int, @ERROR int OUT
AS

BEGIN    

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @TimeOtVal varchar(50)
set @TimeOtVal = (SELECT CASE WHEN [TimeOut] IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[TimeOut]) END FROM tblTime WHERE tId = ( SELECT MAX(tId) FROM tblTime WHERE UserId = @UId))

IF (@TimeOtVal = '') -- condition for the update 

BEGIN -- now action is taken if condition is met

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE tblTime  SET TimeOut = DATEADD(HOUR,8,TimeIn) WHERE tId = ( SELECT MAX(tId) FROM tblTime WHERE UserId = @UId)        
         SET  @ERROR = 1
END
 else

     BEGIN -- Other wise , if condition isnot met 

         SET  @ERROR = -1

     END

END
```

so it does what you want only if you allowed it by the condition 
then reports the action so you can handle it in program  code behind .